# Can't insert on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, server, backend

I'm new at using back-end code.

I'm trying to Insert basic line into MongoDB online DB.

These are my files:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var db = require('./config/db');


const port = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

MongoClient.connect(db.url, (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    db = database.db('note-api');


    require('./app/routes')(app, db);

    require('./app/routes')(app, database);



    app.listen(port, () => {

        console.log('We are live on ' + port);
    });

})
```

note_routes.js:

```
module.exports = function (app, db) {
//    const collection =
    app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
        const note = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
        db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({ 'error': err });
            } else {
                res.send(result.ops[0]);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

db.js:

```
module.exports = {
    url: "mongodb://laelav:laelav1@ds227594.mlab.com:27594/getremp"
};
```

Whenever i try using POST and wish to update the online DB - I get an unauthorized error:
[unauthorized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJIY.png)

Then I added this line in note_routes.js:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("laelav", [{ role: "readWrite", db: "getremp" }]);
```

And got the following "TypeError: db.grantRolesToUser is not a function":
[not a function error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IQDo.png)

Please help!

Comment: What version of mongo are you running?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 4.0.4